# Fourier coefficients of a Holder continous function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

I'm trying to do an exercise in Pinsky's "Introduction to Fourier analysis and wavelets":

> Suppose that $f$ satisfies $L^{2}$ Holder condition with $\alpha=1$. Prove that $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} |n|^{2}|\hat{f}(n)|^{2}<\infty$.

The author suggests applying Fatou's lemma to the fomula:
$$||f_{h}-f||_{2}^{2}=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}|e^{inh}-1|^{2}|\hat{f}(n)|^{2},$$
here $||f_{h}-f||_{2}^{2}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}|f(x+h)-f(x)|^{2}dx$ and the $L^{2}$ Holder condition means $||f_{h}-f||_{2}^{2}\le Kh^{\alpha}$. However I don't know how to use this hint. Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have stated Holder continuity wrongly. In the definition you have $\|f_h-f\|_2 \leq Kh^{\alpha}$ . (No square on the left). Hence We have $\sum |\frac {e^{inh}-1} h|^{2} |\hat {f} (n)|^{2} \leq K$. Now apply Fatou's Lemma. [$\frac {e^{inh}-1} h \to in$ as $h  \to 0$].

Comment: Oh yes, it should be $||f_{h}-f||_{2}\leq Kh^{\alpha}$. But I only know Fatou's lemma for integral, can you tell me what is Fatou's lemma for series?

Comment: @vutuanhien Any infinite sum is an integral w.r.t. counting measure, so Fatou's Lemma applies to series. ($\sum a_n = \int f d\mu$ where $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb R$ is defined by $f(n)=a_n$ and $\mu (E)$ is the number of points of $E$ for any $E \subset \mathbb N$).